# Running Batch File in background when windows boots up

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup, tracd

How do I run a batch file each time windows boots up also I need to run it in the back ground(without that command window getting displayed)? I use Windows Xp.
My actuall requirement is I want to start the Tracd server using the command line commands whenever Windows boots up.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add your program in the [registry](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html):

Run - These are the most common startup locations for programs to install auto start from. By default these keys are not executed in Safe mode. If you prefix the value of these keys with an asterisk, *, is will run in Safe Mode.
Registry Keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key
```

Then you can launch your batch in an [invisible mode](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/run-batch-file-invisiblestealth/14270.html):

```
wscript.exe "C:\yourpath\invis.vbs" "your_file.bat"
```

In invis.vbs put...

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Answer (score 14):

Two other startup posibilties:

- you could always add the bat file to the startup folder,
- or start it as a Scheduled task setting to run on logon.

Comment: I want to run it without the command window gettng popped up.

Comment: The startup folder path can be found using `Win`+`R` and entering `shell:startup`. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd)

Answer (score 5):

You can make an application run as a service.

Check [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) for details:

Answer (score 3):

You can use [autoexnt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243486) for this. It was original designed for windows NT, but is still working in newer versions of windows.

You have to [download the Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) to get it.

Comment: I was thinking windows resource kit would not work on Windows Xp. But it seems it installs on XP too!.. Thanks.

Comment: WOW! your answer is best as i think, as other answers are related after windows log in.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html), a third party program that's worked well for my needs. It's maintained too. The last version was released on July 7, 2010.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this tool, just bought a license :)