# How Do I Compile a C Program to Run Without a Command Box?

Tags: c, process, command-prompt

I need a very simple program to run on any version of Windows, let's say >= Win 98, without requiring any pre-installed framework like dotnet. I thought C would be a great idea to do this.

The program should start a process from the parent directory by using a system command.

> Start C program (invisible) > program starts process > program exits

This is how it looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("..\\someprogram.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

I call this program from a Flash projector, which only allows to start programs in a specific subfolder "fscommand" – but I have to start a process located in the same directory as the projector.

Anyway, it works fine! But the C program opens a command box, then starts the process and leaves the command box open as long as the process runs. So here is how it should work, in order how i would appreciate it:

1. Do not open a command box at all (I'd like that, really ;)
2. Both 3) and 4)
3. Close the command box after starting the process (exit the C program)
4. Open the command box minimized by default

I can't change any Windows settings for the C executable or use a shortcut, as this will run directly from a CD later.

I use Open Watcom to compile my program. Both image types (target options) that produce an executable (Character-mode Executable / Windowed Executable) have the same result.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode A batch file should do the trick.

Comment: or this? http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

Comment: Unfortunately Flash does not allow to call an executable with arguments for security reasons. Only exe- and bat-calls without arguments are possible. (That was one of the greatest ideas Adobe ever had.) I had a nice solution using a batch file instead of the C-program. This was working when starting the bat manually. But when calling it from Flash, it just didn't start the process. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a google search and found http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html

Your using a console app, you could change it to a windows app using `winmain()`

You can use a shortcut to a file in the same folder, not sure why your discounting that method.

`start` will give you a fork so your intermediate app can close - not sure about win98 tho.

```
system("start ..\\someprogram.exe");
```

Instead of system you can use [`createProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to launch the app, theis will avoid the `system` commands console.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

// Start the child process. 
if( !CreateProcess( "..\\someprogram.exe",   // module name 
    NULL,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
) 
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

// Wait until child process exits.  In your case you don't care to wait anyway
// WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Comment: Using WinMain() sounds logical, but still produces a command box. :( Addes line: `#include <windows.h>` and `int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hI, HINSTANCE hPrI, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)`

Comment: This little change `system("start ..\\someprogram.exe");` fits #3 of the behaviors I listet. :) I didn't try the rest of it, because I found a much simpler solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

The console window shows up because you built your program as a console application. I don't know how to avoid that in C, but in Delphi is was a simple `{$Console Off}` pragma in the project file.

GCC has a command line option `-mwindows`, which I think achieves the same, so you could search into this direction.

Comment: Sounds good to me, though I didn't find a way to do something like that in Open Watcom. :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the [_exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx) and/or [_spawn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx) functions do what you need, though I'm not sure.

If not, you can always use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx), though it can be a little more tedious in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could (for example) use [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html) instead of your own program to start that exe.

(This would result in no black box at all.)

Comment: This would be great, but Flash doesn't support arguments for application calls (see my comment above). :(

Answer (score 0):

`CreateProcess` with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag is what you want, but I want to add something. To support also cmd style commands (such as `DIR`, `SET`, ... ) which have no executables and can't be passed to `CreateProcess` alone, you should call `cmd.exe /C someprogram` where `someprogram` is name of executable, bat file, or command.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `system` is doing?

Comment: No @Roland. System also waits created process to end. But via CreateProcess you can do some things in main process untill new process is running.

Answer (score 0):

A friend came up with a completely different solution. Now I use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) with a short compiled script to start the process. This is very simple and the launcher process is completely invisible. :)

```
filename = ..\someprogram.exe

if FileExist(filename) {    
    Run, open %filename%
}
```