# Batch file not executed when trying to run in background

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute some batch file from java class. I want the batch to run without opening cmd window and I want to wait till it is completed.

When using the command below (without the backgroung)  - it works perfectly:

```
String executeCmd = "cmd /c start /wait " +config.getJarPath()+ " --context_param Path=" +folderName;
        final Process process = run.exec(executeCmd);
        process.waitFor();
```

But when I'm adding the /b (run in background) the batch file is not running:

```
String executeCmd = "cmd /c start /B /wait " +config.getJarPath()+ " --context_param Path=" +folderName;
        final Process process = run.exec(executeCmd);
        process.waitFor();
```

Do you have any idea what can it be?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What happens if you run the command manually with /B argument. Does it work

Comment: Just tried to do this and I see something wierd.. The context_param I'm sending being messed up somehow. one of the slashes being converted to ♀ (some wierd char)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `start /b` command tag simply starts the program in the **current** window.

```
B           Start application without creating a new window.
```

If you want to start the batch file as a hidden process there is a simple [vb script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode) which does this.

Alternatively you could use a [Batch-To-Exe converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) and when converting it specify you would like the exe to be a Ghost Application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't work for me. Decided to just go with /min.. not a perfect solution but I can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/B` with `/wait` it works.

E.g. `cmd /c start /B /wait yourbatfile.bat`