# Is there a tag I could add to a ".bat" file to stop command window being displayed

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, ssis, dtexec

Is there a tag I could add to a ".bat" file so that the "CMD" window won't be displayed?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /File "\\sqlbi3\Projects\SSIS\TechOne\AirlineBilling\AirlineBilling\PSE3_Report.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables\[User::BatchId\].Properties\[Value\];"01408" /SET \Package.Variables\[User::UID\].Properties\[Value\];"20200306090134" /SET /Rep EW
```

[image]

I am currently running a DTSX package from a ".bat" file.  The ".bat" file is called by a command line function from a ERP system and everything works well.  However, it would look a lot better if the black command window did not show up (see picture attached).

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: These could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-later-windows-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-with-n

Comment: Also you can use this link [run silent mode](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php)

Comment: A big thanks to @indago for suggestion this solution which worked well for me, I added a .vbs file which called the .bat file as per the instructions here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130366/5692685)

Comment: If your question has been answered, I recommend deleting it to keep things tidy.