# Run Java application as a service

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I would like to run a Java application as a service.  Unfortunately, I am limited in that I can't use something like the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/) (which does appear to be an excellent tool).

Is there any way of running an executable JAR, as a service, without relying on external applications?  I currently have the service installed, but it fails to start.  This is where I am getting stuck and I haven't been able to find anything on Google other than information about the JSW.

Comment: Refers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

Comment: Why can't you use Java Service Wrapper?

Comment: @Kevin - A few different reasons.  First, and foremost, is licensing (GPL - I can't open source the code that this is being applied to).

Comment: Jason, can you use an older version of JSW before they switched the licensing? I don't believe that they retroactively changed the licensing on older versions

Comment: Based on the wording on http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/licenseCommunity.html it is very clear that the Community Edition cannot be used with a non-Open Source program.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415409/535203) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22931661/535203) should help too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an LGPL clone of the Java Service Wrapper: http://yajsw.sourceforge.net

BTW, IANAL, but I suspect that JSW people are spreading FUD, and their software can be used to service-enable commercial applications under GPL license, just like one can gzip a commercial app for redistribution. I could be completely wrong about this, though :)

Comment: Based on the wording on wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/licenseCommunity.html it is very clear that the Community Edition cannot be used with a non-Open Source program due to it being under the GPL.

Comment: GPL does not preclude non-Open Source programs from being used "with" GPL programs (e.g. it's perfectly fine to run commercial applications on Linux OS). It only precludes creating a derivative work by linking against GPL code and releasing it under non-GPL license. In this case, It's not clear to me that a derivative work is being created.

Comment: Meh, you might be right. They distribute their stuff not under GPL, but under some weird license that requires distributed product software to be distributed under GPL regardless of it being a derivative product. I wonder if this is legal... but I guess it's best to assume that it is.

Answer (score 11):

Another option, Apache Commons Daemon's procrun.

See http://commons.apache.org/daemon/

Comment: This one is the only free option that supports 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

A program that should run as windows service must provide certain functions that the windows service manager uses to communicate with that service.

As long as there is no JVM that implements this functions directly (and I know of none) you will need some kind of wrapper.

I have successfully used [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B137890&x=16&y=7) for a java based windows service (Basically it allows to run any program as windows service and it works fine with java)

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the question; all the others mention yet another external tool that the OP is looking to avoid. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) like this:

```
nssm install MyService "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "path\to\the\file.jar"
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it (yet), but [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) looks like it could suit your needs.

Comment: Doesn't register as a service but its a nice option for packaging user programs that don't run as a service.

Answer (score 1):

one more option [winrun4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/). the license is eclipse's CPL.

Comment: yes, but like the other service wrappers, requires that you implement the public interface in order to integrate your app into the service handler.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I found was [RunAsService](http://sourceforge.net/projects/runasservice/).

A co-worker recommended a tool called [SC](http://www.winhelpline.info/daten/dos/sc.php), but I did not try it.

Answer (score 0):

JSmooth can do it, and it is scriptable with ant.

Comment: It appears that the service wrapper start breaking under Windows 7 :(