# How to run solr on a windows server so it starts up automatically?

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, solr

How can I run solr on a windows server, so it starts up automatically?

I run it with:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

but I need the server to do this automatically.

Comment: I guess windows server can be started as a windows service and the java command itself could wrap into a bat file and also be added as a windows service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a batch file with the command you need and run it on startup: some of [these](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/Startup.htm) ideas might be of use.

If you ran solr inside tomcat, you could start tomcat as a windows service and set the service to start automatically.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you are deploying a .WAR file inside of IIS?  Or are you using IIS as a frontend to some other webcontainer?   I think you can't deploy inside of IIS, that you need to have something like Jetty (which is what you are using with java -jar start.jar) or Tomcat.

Comment: Good point, Eric. IIS is not a servlet container: Blankman is probably simply using it as a frontend to jetty. In that case, my suggestion of using it with tomcat might make sense. Otherwise, Jetty can be set up as a windows service as well: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Win32Wrapper

Answer (score 7):

I've had good luck with the "Non-Sucking Service Manager" to do this exact thing.  Very simple and lightweight: http://nssm.cc/

Answer (score 3):

The Scheduled Tasks feature in Windows Server will let you configure your command to be executed at startup, without the use of a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I will add the small solr windwos service installer that I found and updated recently :

https://github.com/serbrech/SolrWindowsService

First Update the App.config

```
<add key="JavaExecutable" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" />
<add key="WorkingDirectory" value="C:\Solr\apache-solr-4.0\example" />
<add key="Solr.Home" value="solr" />
<add key="CommandLineArgs" value="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties" />
<add key="ShowConsole" value="false" />
<add key="Port" value="8983" />
<add key="InstanceName" value="Pageplanner" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
```

Then run install.bat That's all there is to it.