# Run Solr 6.0.1 in background on Windows server

Tags: solr, windows-server-2012-r2, solr6

I'd like to start a solr core (version 6.0.1) on Windows Server 2012 R2(command is: bin\solr.cmd start), and keep it running after logging off.  I'd also like to run it under an account other than my own, and I'd like it to start up automatically.  I came across this post, [How to run solr on a windows server so it starts up automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531038/how-to-run-solr-on-a-windows-server-so-it-starts-up-automatically), but it was from 6 years ago, so I thought there may be a new way with the new version.  Also, the new version I have is not running on Tomcat.  It acts as it's own server, which is another difference from the version in the example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download) to [register Solr as a Windows Service](https://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/).

> "c:\Program Files\nssm\win64\nssm" install solr6

It's important that you use the `-f` parameter to run Solr in the foreground (which in this case means "run it inside NSSM"). This can be changed in the box that pops up for NSSM ("Arguments"). You can also pick which user to run the service as under "Log on".

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link, that was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in PowerShell without any external components.  This is what I'm currently using with Solr 7.5.0 to install and run as a native Windows service.  I'm reasonably certain this will work with any version that uses bin\solr.cmd on Server 2012 R2.

You need to create an environment variable called SOLR_HOME and set the value to the full path of your Solr \bin directory, and possibly reboot to pick up that new environment variable.  Make any necessary changes, especially to memory and port under `#region Solr configuration`.  Then you drop the code below in a file named PSSolrService.ps1 in your Solr root directory, cd to that directory in a PowerShell console, and then run the setup command: `./PSService.ps1 -Setup`  This should give you a Windows service called Solr which is set to run automatically at system startup.  You can also then use `NET STOP Solr` and `NET START Solr` to stop and start the service, just like any other Windows service.

```
#
# PSSolrService.ps1
#
#Requires -version 2

<#
  .SYNOPSIS
    A simple Windows service, in a standalone PowerShell script.

  .DESCRIPTION
    This script demonstrates how to write a Windows service in pure PowerShell.
    It dynamically generates a small PSService.exe wrapper, that in turn
    invokes this PowerShell script again for its start and stop events.

  .PARAMETER Start
    Start the service.

  .PARAMETER Stop
    Stop the service.

  .PARAMETER Restart
    Stop then restart the service.

  .PARAMETER Status
    Get the current service status: Not installed / Stopped / Running

  .PARAMETER Setup
    Install the service.

  .PARAMETER Remove
    Uninstall the service.

  .PARAMETER Service
    Run the service in the background. Used internally by the script.
    Do not use, except for test purposes.

  .PARAMETER Control
    Send a control message to the service thread.

  .PARAMETER Version
    Display this script version and exit.

  .EXAMPLE
    # Setup the service and run it for the first time
    C:\PS>.\PSService.ps1 -Status
    Not installed
    C:\PS>.\PSService.ps1 -Setup
    C:\PS># At this stage, a copy of PSService.ps1 is present in the path
    C:\PS>PSService -Status
    Stopped
    C:\PS>PSService -Start
    C:\PS>PSService -Status
    Running
    C:\PS># Load the log file in Notepad.exe for review
    C:\PS>notepad ${ENV:windir}\Logs\PSService.log

  .EXAMPLE
    # Stop the service and uninstall it.
    C:\PS>PSService -Stop
    C:\PS>PSService -Status
    Stopped
    C:\PS>PSService -Remove
    C:\PS># At this stage, no copy of PSService.ps1 is present in the path anymore
    C:\PS>.\PSService.ps1 -Status
    Not installed

  .EXAMPLE
    # Send a control message to the service, and verify that it received it.
    C:\PS>PSService -Control Hello
    C:\PS>Notepad C:\Windows\Logs\PSService.log
    # The last lines should contain a trace of the reception of this Hello message
#>

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Status')]
Param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Start', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Start,               # Start the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Stop', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Stop,                # Stop the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Restart', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Restart,             # Restart the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Status', Mandatory=$false)]
  [Switch]$Status = $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Status'), # Get the current service status

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Setup', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Setup,               # Install the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Remove', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Remove,              # Uninstall the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Service', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Service,             # Run the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Control', Mandatory=$true)]
  [String]$Control = $null,     # Control message to send to the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Version', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Version              # Get this script version
)

# modify this to update script version used by Solr Service
$scriptVersion = "2018-11-07"

if( -not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    Write-Warning  -Message "Please run thisscript with Administrator permissions."
    return
}

#region Solr configuration
 $solrPort = '8983' 
 $solrMemory = '12g' # eg. 1g 4g
 $solrHome = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SOLR_HOME",[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)  
 $solrRoot =  Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $solrHome -Parent) -Parent
 $sorlStartCmd = Join-Path -Path $solrRoot -ChildPath "bin\solr.cmd"

 if( -not (Test-Path -Path $sorlStartCmd) )
 {
    Write-Warning "Solr.cmd not exist: $sorlStartCmd"
    return
 }
#endregion

# This script name, with various levels of details
$argv0 = Get-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$script = $argv0.basename               # Ex: PSSolrService
$scriptName = $argv0.name               # Ex: PSSolrService.ps1
$scriptFullName = $argv0.fullname       # Ex: C:\Temp\PSSolrService.ps1

# Global settings
$serviceName = $script                  # A one-word name used for net start commands
$serviceDisplayName = "Solr"
$ServiceDescription = "Solr"

$installDir = "${ENV:ProgramFiles}\$serviceName" # Where to install the service files

#$installDir = "${ENV:windir}\System32"  # Where to install the service files

$scriptCopy = "$installDir\$scriptName"
$exeName = "$serviceName.exe"
$exeFullName = "$installDir\$exeName"
$logDir = "${ENV:windir}\Logs"          # Where to log the service messages
$logFile = "$logDir\$serviceName.log"
$logName = "Application"                # Event Log name (Unrelated to the logFile!)
# Note: The current implementation only supports "classic" (ie. XP-compatble) event logs.
#   To support new style (Vista and later) "Applications and Services Logs" folder trees, it would
#   be necessary to use the new *WinEvent commands instead of the XP-compatible *EventLog commands.
# Gotcha: If you change $logName to "NEWLOGNAME", make sure that the registry key below does not exist:
#         HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\NEWLOGNAME
#     Else, New-EventLog will fail, saying the log NEWLOGNAME is already registered as a source,
#     even though "Get-WinEvent -ListLog NEWLOGNAME" says this log does not exist!

# If the -Version switch is specified, display the script version and exit.
if ($Version) {
  Write-Output $scriptVersion
  return
}

Function Now {
  Param (
    [Switch]$ms,        # Append milliseconds
    [Switch]$ns         # Append nanoseconds
  )
  $Date = Get-Date
  $now = ""
  $now += "{0:0000}-{1:00}-{2:00} " -f $Date.Year, $Date.Month, $Date.Day
  $now += "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}" -f $Date.Hour, $Date.Minute, $Date.Second
  $nsSuffix = ""
  if ($ns) {
    if ("$($Date.TimeOfDay)" -match "\.\d\d\d\d\d\d") {
      $now += $matches[0]
      $ms = $false
    } else {
      $ms = $true
      $nsSuffix = "000"
    }
  } 
  if ($ms) {
    $now += ".{0:000}$nsSuffix" -f $Date.MilliSecond
  }
  return $now
}

Function Log () {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)]
    [String]$string
  )
  if (!(Test-Path $logDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $logDir | Out-Null
  }
  if ($String.length) {
    $string = "$(Now) $pid $userName $string"
  }
  $string | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -Append "$logFile"
}

$scriptCopyCname = $scriptCopy -replace "\\", "\\" # Double backslashes. (The first \\ is a regexp with \ escaped; The second is a plain string.)
$source = @"
  using System;
  using System.ServiceProcess;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;                                 // SET STATUS
  using System.ComponentModel;                                          // SET STATUS

  public enum ServiceType : int {                                       // SET STATUS [
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010,
    SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS = 0x00000020,
  };                                                                    // SET STATUS ]

  public enum ServiceState : int {                                      // SET STATUS [
    SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
    SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
    SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
    SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
  };                                                                    // SET STATUS ]

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]                                 // SET STATUS [
  public struct ServiceStatus {
    public ServiceType dwServiceType;
    public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
    public int dwControlsAccepted;
    public int dwWin32ExitCode;
    public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
    public int dwCheckPoint;
    public int dwWaitHint;
  };                                                                    // SET STATUS ]

  public enum Win32Error : int { // WIN32 errors that we may need to use
    NO_ERROR = 0,
    ERROR_APP_INIT_FAILURE = 575,
    ERROR_FATAL_APP_EXIT = 713,
    ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE = 1062,
    ERROR_EXCEPTION_IN_SERVICE = 1064,
    ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR = 1066,
    ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED = 1067,
  };

  public class Service_$serviceName : ServiceBase { // $serviceName may begin with a digit; The class name must begin with a letter
    private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog;                       // EVENT LOG
    private ServiceStatus serviceStatus;                                // SET STATUS

    public Service_$serviceName() {
      ServiceName = "$serviceName";
      CanStop = true;
      CanPauseAndContinue = false;
      AutoLog = true;

      eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();                     // EVENT LOG [
      if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(ServiceName)) {         
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(ServiceName, "$logName");
      }
      eventLog.Source = ServiceName;
      eventLog.Log = "$logName";                                        // EVENT LOG ]
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName $serviceName()");      // EVENT LOG
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]                      // SET STATUS
    private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);

    protected override void OnStart(string [] args) {
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName OnStart() // Entry. Starting script '$scriptCopyCname' -Start"); // EVENT LOG
      // Set the service state to Start Pending.                        // SET STATUS [
      // Only useful if the startup time is long. Not really necessary here for a 2s startup time.
      serviceStatus.dwServiceType = ServiceType.SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
      serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
      serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
      serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 2000; // It takes about 2 seconds to start PowerShell
      SetServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);               // SET STATUS ]
      // Start a child process with another copy of this script
      try {
        Process p = new Process();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c & '$scriptCopyCname' -Start"; // Works if path has spaces, but not if it contains ' quotes.
        p.Start();
        // Read the output stream first and then wait. (To avoid deadlocks says Microsoft!)
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // Wait for the completion of the script startup code, that launches the -Service instance
        p.WaitForExit();
        if (p.ExitCode != 0) throw new Win32Exception((int)(Win32Error.ERROR_APP_INIT_FAILURE));
        // Success. Set the service state to Running.                   // SET STATUS
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;    // SET STATUS
      } catch (Exception e) {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName OnStart() // Failed to start $scriptCopyCname. " + e.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error); // EVENT LOG
        // Change the service state back to Stopped.                    // SET STATUS [
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;
        Win32Exception w32ex = e as Win32Exception; // Try getting the WIN32 error code
        if (w32ex == null) { // Not a Win32 exception, but maybe the inner one is...
          w32ex = e.InnerException as Win32Exception;
        }    
        if (w32ex != null) {    // Report the actual WIN32 error
          serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = w32ex.NativeErrorCode;
        } else {                // Make up a reasonable reason
          serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = (int)(Win32Error.ERROR_APP_INIT_FAILURE);
        }                                                               // SET STATUS ]
      } finally {
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;                                   // SET STATUS
        SetServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);             // SET STATUS
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName OnStart() // Exit"); // EVENT LOG
      }
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName OnStop() // Entry");   // EVENT LOG
      // Start a child process with another copy of ourselves
      Process p = new Process();
      // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
      p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      p.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe";
      p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c & '$scriptCopyCname' -Stop"; // Works if path has spaces, but not if it contains ' quotes.
      p.Start();
      // Read the output stream first and then wait.
      string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      // Wait for the PowerShell script to be fully stopped.
      p.WaitForExit();
      // Change the service state back to Stopped.                      // SET STATUS
      serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;      // SET STATUS
      SetServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);               // SET STATUS
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "$exeName OnStop() // Exit");    // EVENT LOG
    }

    public static void Main() {
      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new Service_$serviceName());
    }
  }
"@

# Check if we're running as a real user, or as the SYSTEM = As a service
$identity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$userName = $identity.Name      # Ex: "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" or "Domain\Administrator"
$authority,$name = $username -split "\\"
$isSystem = $identity.IsSystem  # Do not test ($userName -eq "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"), as this fails in non-English systems.
# Log "# `$userName = `"$userName`" ; `$isSystem = $isSystem"

if ($Setup) {Log ""}    # Insert one blank line to separate test sessions logs
Log $MyInvocation.Line # The exact command line that was used to start us

# The following commands write to the event log, but we need to make sure the PSService source is defined.
New-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -ea SilentlyContinue

# Workaround for PowerShell v2 bug: $PSCmdlet Not yet defined in Param() block
$Status = ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Status')

if ($Start) {                   # Start the service
  if ($isSystem) { # If running as SYSTEM, ie. invoked as a service
    # Do whatever is necessary to start the service script instance
    Log "$scriptName -Start: Starting script '$scriptFullName' -Service"
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1001 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Start: Starting script '$scriptFullName' -Service"
    Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList ("-c & '$scriptFullName' -Service")
  } else {
    Write-Verbose "Starting service $serviceName"
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1002 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Start: Starting service $serviceName"
    Start-Service $serviceName # Ask Service Control Manager to start it
  }
  return
}

if ($Stop) {                    # Stop the service
  if ($isSystem) { # If running as SYSTEM, ie. invoked as a service
    # Do whatever is necessary to stop the service script instance
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1003 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Stop: Stopping script $scriptName -Service"
    Log "$scriptName -Stop: Stopping script $scriptName -Service"

#region Solr stop  
    &$sorlStartCmd stop -p $solrPort
#endregion

  } else {
    Write-Verbose "Stopping service $serviceName"
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1004 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Stop: Stopping service $serviceName"
    Stop-Service $serviceName # Ask Service Control Manager to stop it
  }
  return
}

if ($Restart) {                 # Restart the service
  & $scriptFullName -Stop
  & $scriptFullName -Start
  return
}

if ($Status) {                  # Get the current service status
  $spid = $null
  $processes = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "Name = 'powershell.exe'" | Where-Object {
    $_.CommandLine -match ".*$scriptCopyCname.*-Service"
  })
  foreach ($process in $processes) { # There should be just one, but be prepared for surprises.
    $spid = $process.ProcessId
    Write-Verbose "$serviceName Process ID = $spid"
  }
  # if (Test-Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\$serviceName") {}
  try {
    $pss = Get-Service $serviceName -ea stop # Will error-out if not installed
  } catch {
    "Not Installed"
    return
  }
  $pss.Status
  if (($pss.Status -eq "Running") -and (!$spid)) { # This happened during the debugging phase
    Write-Error "The Service Control Manager thinks $serviceName is started, but $serviceName.ps1 -Service is not running."
    exit 1
  }
  return
}

if ($Setup) {                   # Install the service
  # Check if it's necessary
  try {
    $pss = Get-Service $serviceName -ea stop # Will error-out if not installed
    # Check if this script is newer than the installed copy.
    if ((Get-Item $scriptCopy -ea SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Item $scriptFullName -ea SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime) {
      Write-Verbose "Service $serviceName is already Installed, but requires upgrade"
      & $scriptFullName -Remove
      throw "continue"
    } else {
      Write-Verbose "Service $serviceName is already Installed, and up-to-date"
    }
    exit 0
  } catch {
    # This is the normal case here. Do not throw or write any error!
    Write-Debug "Installation is necessary" # Also avoids a ScriptAnalyzer warning
    # And continue with the installation.
  }
  if (!(Test-Path $installDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $installDir | Out-Null
  }
  # Copy the service script into the installation directory
  if ($ScriptFullName -ne $scriptCopy) {
    Write-Verbose "Installing $scriptCopy"
    Copy-Item $ScriptFullName $scriptCopy
  }
  # Generate the service .EXE from the C# source embedded in this script
  try {
    Write-Verbose "Compiling $exeFullName"
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharp -OutputAssembly $exeFullName -OutputType ConsoleApplication -ReferencedAssemblies "System.ServiceProcess" -Debug:$false
  } catch {
    $msg = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-error "Failed to create the $exeFullName service stub. $msg"
    exit 1
  }
  # Register the service
  Write-Verbose "Registering service $serviceName"
  $pss = New-Service $serviceName $exeFullName -DisplayName $serviceDisplayName -Description $ServiceDescription -StartupType Automatic

  return
}

if ($Remove) {                  # Uninstall the service
  # Check if it's necessary
  try {
    $pss = Get-Service $serviceName -ea stop # Will error-out if not installed
  } catch {
    Write-Verbose "Already uninstalled"
    return
  }
  Stop-Service $serviceName # Make sure it's stopped
  # In the absence of a Remove-Service applet, use sc.exe instead.
  Write-Verbose "Removing service $serviceName"
  $msg = sc.exe delete $serviceName
  if ($LastExitCode) {
    Write-Error "Failed to remove the service ${serviceName}: $msg"
    exit 1
  } else {
    Write-Verbose $msg
  }
  # Remove the installed files
  if (Test-Path $installDir) {
    foreach ($ext in ("exe", "pdb", "ps1")) {
      $file = "$installDir\$serviceName.$ext"
      if (Test-Path $file) {
        Write-Verbose "Deleting file $file"
        Remove-Item $file
      }
    }
    if (!(@(Get-ChildItem $installDir -ea SilentlyContinue)).Count) {
      Write-Verbose "Removing directory $installDir"
      Remove-Item $installDir
    }
  }
  return
}

if ($Service) {                 # Run the service
  Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1005 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Service # Beginning background job"
  # Do the service background job
  try 
  {

#region Solr start
      Log "$scriptName Starting $sorlStartCmd with parameteres start -f -p $solrPort -m $solrMemory"
      &$sorlStartCmd start -f -p $solrPort -m $solrMemory
#endregion

  } 
  catch 
  { # An exception occurred while runnning the service
    $msg = $_.Exception.Message
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    Log "$scriptName -Service # Error at line ${line}: $msg"
  } 
  finally 
  { 
    # Invoked in all cases: Exception or normally by -Stop

    # Flush all leftover events (There may be some that arrived after we exited the while event loop, but before we unregistered the events)
    $events = Get-Event | Remove-Event
    # Log a termination event, no matter what the cause is.
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1006 -EntryType Information -Message "$script -Service # Exiting"
    Log "$scriptName -Service # Exiting"
  }
  return
}
```