# Solr stops on closing windows command prompt

Tags: windows, solr, command-prompt

Following this documentation, 
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/running-solr.html,

I start Solr from the command prompt using `solr.cmd start`. The process begins in the background and Solr starts successfully.
However, when I close the command prompt, solr server stops.

I have also tried `START "" solr.cmd start`. The result is still same.

How do I ensure that the server continue to run even after closing command prompt?

Comment: You need to run solr as a service if you want it to persist. There is a few question that are similar, I think this might be helpfull.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889521/run-solr-6-0-1-in-background-on-windows-server