# How to run python script once in a day that is creating back-up copy of network dir?

Tags: python, copy, save, backup

I want to take back-up copy of my network dirs once in a day on specified time, Below is the code of my current work by which i am running it manually.

So i want to do this manual work as windows service which creates a back-up copy of specified network dir on particular time.

```
import tarfile
import datetime

def backup_htmls():
    tar = tarfile.open('./InputHTML_bc/'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')+".tar.gz", "w:gz")
    tar.add('\\\\192.168.211.65\\shared\\InputHTML\\', arcname="Backup_Tar")
    tar.close()
```

I have the reference of how to run it as a windows service;

i just want how can i run this job once in a day on particular time(for example if i pass time as a parameter to python function and it will execute it once for that day.. or any other way you can do it.. in pythonic way)??? 
i know it will be very easy but i am not getting the idea from where i can start
anyway of doing it???

Comment: No need for a service, just use the [windows scheduller](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task).

Comment: If you are on a linux environment, use cron job to run it once a day at a specific time.

Comment: @ronak: from the OP question: i want to run it as a service on windows

Comment: I know the reference of how to run it as a service; i just want how can i run this job once in a day on particular time??? i know it will be very easy but i am not getting the idea from where i can start

Comment: Use `r''` literals to avoid using so many backslashes: `r'\\192.168.211.65\shared\InputHTML'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe that shows you how to create a windows service using Python:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576451-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

There is this: http://runasservice.sourceforge.net/

Which was referenced in this similar question:

[Run batch file as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service)

And as a batch file can start your python up....