# PHP CLI program run in background

Tags: php, windows, background, rabbitmq

I am using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) Messaging service to run some background services. The problem I am facing is that I have keep open my command line which runs a script continuously

`php receive_messages.php`

Is it possible that these scripts run in background as soon as I start my rabbit MQ server or WAMP?

In linux I can use some programs like forever but in windows ???

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-di ( and a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

Try running a PHP script in a while loop and run in with screen.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
ignore_user_abort(true);    
set_time_limit(0); 

while(true) { 
   echo 'Running..'; // Code here
   sleep (60); // Sleep 60 seconds
}
```

Command for cmd (first start cmd by pressing alt + r and then type cmd) with:

```
start /B php.exe myscript.php
```

Comment: The q is about win platform