# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError procrun

Tags: java, procrun, system-services

I tried to make my java application a windows service via procrun.
but when I start the service I get the following error:

```
2019-06-07 17:19:25 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SaveData 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SaveData 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" 

2019-06-07 17:19:25] [error] [25304] FindClass SaveData  failed
[2019-06-07 17:19:25] [error] [21836] Failed to start Java
[2019-06-07 17:19:25] [error] [21836] ServiceStart returned 4
[2019-06-07 17:19:25] [info]  [ 8688] Run service finished.
[2019-06-07 17:19:25] [info]  [ 8688] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

can someone help me? thank you

### file batch for the installation

```
set SERVICE_NAME=TestService
set PR_INSTALL=C:\Users\sergi\Desktop\SaveData\prunsrv.exe
REM Service log configuration 
set PR_LOGPREFIX=%SERVICE_NAME% 
set PR_LOGPATH=%~dp0%
set PR_STDOUTPUT=%~dp0%\stdout.txt 
set PR_STDERROR=%~dp0%\stderr.txt 
set PR_LOGLEVEL=Error   
REM path to java installation
set PR_JVM=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\server\jvm.dll
set PR_CLASSPATH=C:\Users\sergi\Desktop\SaveData\testservice.jar
REM Startup configuration
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=SaveData 
set PR_STARTMETHOD=main
REM Shutdown configuration 
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm 
set PR_STOPCLASS=SaveData
set PR_STOPMETHOD=main
REM JVM configuration 
set PR_JVMMS=256 
set PR_JVMMX=1024 
set PR_JVMSS=4000 
REM JVM options 
set prunsrv_port=8080 
set prunsrv_server=localhost
REM Install service 
C:\Users\sergi\Desktop\SaveData\prunsrv.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
```

Comment: Are you able to run your jar file using command like java -jar <yourjarfile.jar> and are you able to get the output ?

Comment: it works, "java -jar SaveData.jar" what could be the problem? this class starts a thread that retrieves data and saves it on the database (postgreSQL) and sleeps 1 minute and then repeats

Comment: So it means your jar file dependes on other jar files like postgress jdbc driver. You have to create a fat jar for this.

Comment: I just created the fat jar, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Copy the jar file to a different location and try to run as java -jar <jarfile>.jar. Check is it working or not.

Comment: it works, can it be due to an error in the batch file?

Comment: So you have tried to narrow down the issue, now you can check the batch file to create service.

Comment: the batch file creates the service, but when I start it "start prunmgr.exe // MS // TestService" in the stderr file there is the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SaveData reported above

Comment: Can you post the Manifest.mf file in this question. You will find this file inside your fat jar.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: savedata.SaveData

Comment: I changed "set PR_STARTCLASS = savedata.SaveData" but the error is still the same

Comment: In PR_CLASSPATH, set only testservice.jar, in the same current directory.

Comment: Done, but nothing. how is it possible ?

Comment: You have mentioned as set PR_STARTCLASS=SaveData, can you add the complete class name with package name ?

Comment: I set "set PR_STARTCLASS=savedata.SaveData"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a technology like Springboot, it has its own launcher. Check out your Manifest file inside your jar and you will find which is the real entry point for your jar under the label "Main-Class". For instance, for Springboot you will find something like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Version: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.0.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.yourcompany.application.YourApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
```

Before launching YourApplication, Springboot must initialize everything for the framework, so the entry point of this jar would be the JarLauncher class. So, in this case, you should change your settings to

```
set PR_STARTCLASS=org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

This should be enough to start your service (this is your question). If you also want to handle the STOP service signal, then check this out: [Spring boot JAR as windows service.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124062/spring-boot-jar-as-windows-service)