# service to perform scheduled task operation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, service, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to create a Windows Scheduled Task from a Windows batch file with another batchfile as a parameter:

```
For eg : schtasks.exe /create /tn "taskName" /tr "%Home%\bin\bootstrap.cmd" /sc DAILY /st 00:01:00 /ri 1 /du 0023:59 %schTaskAccountArgs%"
```

**Background**
The batch file `'bootstrap.cmd'` in the script above has calls to other batchfiles and eventually an exe. It creates a scheduled task in the Microsoft console which triggers the same exe, but in my case due to a GPO policy, the scheduled task couldn't be created ***(policy being-not able to store passwords for the user that runs the scheduled job)***. As a workaround I want to create a service in the same Batch file by replacing the above by:

```
sc create "service for taskName" start= demand displayname= "service for taskName" binpath= "%Home%\bin\bootstrap.cmd"
```

is it a feasible method to create a service for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows appears to not run .bat (and .cmd) files as services.**

Here are some alternatives:

1. Create a scheduled task that runs at
   startup.
2. Convert the .cmd into an executable. See [How can a .bat
   file be 'converted' to .exe without third party tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools)
3. Use external tools (like [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/usage) featured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service))

Comment: thanks, I can't create a scheduled task since the server security policy won't let me do that (not able to save password) and the job needs to be done by a user that is not logged in. So I am creating a service that performs the job, and the Log-On could be changed to this user. The conversion of batch script such that it creates a service is the issue as of now.