# Calling a WebAPI continuosly from another WebAPI

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I've a requirement for which I need to have WebAPI get method, which should latest records of a table, and this api get method will be continuosly called from another webAPI method continously to insert the data into the tables.

We are bound to have two webAPIs as we cannot directly interact with the database due to security issues. Could someone please suggest the best approach for implementing this.

One way I know is to call the get WEBAPI method, from the APP_start of the calling WebAPI within a timer. Please suggest the approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Web API's are message based. There's no such as 'continuously'. There are other communication methods besides Web API's that do support continuous (such as a a windows service or message queue). Its strange that direct interaction is not available but web API's are? You might find that repeated web API calls are as good as 'continuous' anyway

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid Approach we have taken is to schedule a console app from Windows Scheduler to run in regular intervals. This calls the first api using HttpClient, and the from api action task, we are calling another api as per requirement using HttpClient.PostAsync().

Answer (score 1):

Approach we have taken is to schedule a console app from Windows Scheduler to run in regular intervals. This calls the first api using HttpClient, and the from api action task, we are calling another api as per requirement using HttpClient.PostAsync().

Comment: Thanks for returning with an answer. The next level of reliability for this would be to create an actual windows service that does this.

Comment: Can you elaborate what problems windows scheduling a console app can cause ? Thanks @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I could try but most likely someone has already explained better than me... like this person https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721851/is-it-good-to-have-windows-service-or-console-application

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful