# run bat file in background

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a bat file in background. I searched in google and I found some examples using hstart and cmdow. But Isn't anyway to do this with windows commands? I really feal good when I don't add extra programs to my project !
thanx in advance

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using window scheduler. I found a way :

Save this one line of text as file invisible.vbs:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

thanx

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the programming language and platform you are using.

In Windows, using the C# language on the .NET platform, it is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\myfile.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the batch file as a windows service. You will perhaps need to have admin previleges on your host to do this, but if you want to go for it, its easy to add/configure using sc command.