# creating a bat file which sends to background and closes (1 file)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

im trying to do something simple, i want to start Burp Suite with extra java memory, but i don't want the CMD window to stay open.

If i don't use a .bat file and simple open cmd and type `start /b "" java -jar -Xmx2g burpsuite_pro_v1.6.07.jar`, Burp opens, the the process is sent to background, but the CMD window stays open. i can, however, close it manually and Burp will keep working.

when i try to put the thing into a CMD window, it will not even be sent to background, Burp stays dependent on the CMD, and i cant even add exit to the file.

i tried to solve the issue by following:
[run bat file in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706075/run-bat-file-in-background) - this worked, but required me to have THREE files, i prefer a more elegant "1 file solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simple: using javaw.
the issue was with using java.exe, some attempts even closed the CMD but opened a java.exe window (blank)

modding the file to contain:
`start javaw -Xmx2g -jar burpsuite_pro_v1.6.07.jar` solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the below line in your bat file and the java procees will run in background with no window open!

```
start javaw {Path of Your jar or Java file}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following batch file commands should accomplish your purpose:

```
start "" /B java.exe -Xmx2g -jar burpsuite_pro_v1.6.07.jar
exit
```

You can probably even leave out the `/B` switch.

References

[How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-having-the-console-open-after)

[How to use the start command in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201507/how-to-use-the-start-command-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: When i do the above i: Burp opens, and i get an open CMD window which is attacked to the process and has two lines in it, as in the file. its as if it just echoed exit but didn't execute. if i close the window burp also exits.