# Script to check battery status variable and use it in if statement, and is there any script to make .bat file run as a hidden process every minute

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing, batterylevel

Currently, I am trying to create a script file that will launch other programs if it detects that the laptop is running using its battery, not the AC.

Providing that I am using Windows 8.1.

I created a `.bat` file and I entered the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM To Check the battery status, providing that 2 is connected to the AC
WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus 
REM Check the content of battery status variable
IF NOT "%BatteryStatus%"=="2"(
echo laptop started to use its battery )
```

When I ran the above batch file its as if not detecting the content of `BatteryStatus` variable.

Can any one guide me to the best way to get batterystatus output in to battery status variable?

Another thing, I need a script to allow this bat to run and do this battery check every minute, how can I achieve that?

I tried to do it using task scheduler, but the problem that the maximum re occurrence time is 5 minute.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus` by `for /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus') do set BatteryStatus=%%A`, because `WMIC` does _not_ set a variable...

Comment: Use `ping localhost -n 60 >nul` or `timeout /t 60 /nobreak` to pause the program for 60 seconds, after that, use a `goto` to create a loop with the code you want to run every 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more robust, check that the variable is really `batterystatus`:

```
    for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl') do @if "%%a"=="BatteryStatus" call :DoStuff %%b
    goto :EOF

:DoStuff
    do_thing1  >nul
    do_thing2 >nul
    do_thing3 >nul
    goto :EOF
```

Then, use a loop to continue the process:

```
:LOOP
for /f .....

timeout /t 60

goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of "timeout" before -- thanks for that one!

Comment: No problem, and just to be official here, the syntax should be `timeout /t 60` Also, `/nobreak` could be added to prevent press-key cancellation, and `>nul` could be added at the end to prevent output to console

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i how to add multiple process to run if the battery status is not equal 2 , i mean not only echo command that i want to execute if the battery status is anything except 2 , i have other commands like running other programs .. but not only echo, can you assist on this?

Comment: also how to hide the console from showing up? where to add this >nul?

Comment: I don't think you can hide the console entirely, but you can use "Start /b CMD /C MyBatchfile.bat" - which will create the new CMD window minimized. Well, if you use taskscheduler it has a "Hidden" option and "run whether the user is logged in or not" - which basically will run the process on a separate desktop from the logged in user.

Comment: @joeking You could run it in the background with a VBScript... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706075/run-bat-file-in-background

Comment: i tried to echo the value of %%b by runing echo %%b command inside the dostaff and its not working, am i did it correctly ?

Comment: Its a parameter in DoStuff, so use "%1". Try "call /?" for more details on what you can do with arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is what I meant in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688409/script-to-check-battery-status-variable-and-use-it-in-if-statement-and-is-there#comment51319004_31688409):

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
REM To Check the battery status, providing that 2 is connected to the AC
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus 2^>^&1') DO SET BatteryStatus=%%A
SET /A BatteryStatus+=0
REM Check the content of battery status variable
IF %BatteryStatus% EQU 2 (
ECHO laptop is running on AC power
) ELSE IF %BatteryStatus% GEQ 1 (
ECHO laptop started to use its battery
) ELSE ECHO unknown battery status
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK > nul
GOTO :LOOP
```

This also features the loop as mentioned by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688409/script-to-check-battery-status-variable-and-use-it-in-if-statement-and-is-there#comment51319042_31688409).

I added the `2>&1` portion to the `WMIC` command to redirect potential error messages as it might return a message like `No Instance(s) Available.`.
The additional `SET /A` command immediately after ensures that variable `%BatteryStatus%` is never empty, even in case of said errors. There are additional checks to distinguish between running on battery, running on AC power and running in an unknown state (the former `IF NOT "%BatteryStatus%"=="2"` could be misleading in case of errors).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make it work with my needs:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
REM To Check the battery status, providing that 2 is connected to the AC
for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus /format:textvaluelist.xsl') do @if "BatteryStatus"=="%%a" call :DoStaff "%%b"
:DoStaff
if  %~1 NEQ 2 (
ECHO laptop started to use its battery
) 
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK > nul
GOTO :LOOP
```

I hope that i could hide the batch box some how, but anyway, thank you all for your help, 
its really appreciated!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this in as a potential answer to a minor part of the question. You can hide the window by adding a `powershell` line in your `batch`:

```
powershell -window hidden -command ""
```

Note that you will still see the initial cmd window flash at startup but it will immediately disappear and continue running in the background.