# How can I run hg commands in the background (without showing the command prompt window)?

Tags: mercurial, firefox-addon

I am using firefox extension to run hg commands on my repository. But when ever I execute any hg commands it shows command prompt window for a split second and closes it.

Eg:-

1. process.run("push");
2. process.run("update");

Is there any way to not show that window at all ?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis help?

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I used to have a tool that was `hidewin.exe` that would all you to start any bat file or exe file and have it run invisibly. I tried a google search for it but didn't find it easily but maybe you could have better luck at finding it.