# Has anyone used "hstart.exe"?

Tags: mercurial, firefox-addon

What I trying to do is to run hg commands using firefox extension without showing command prompt window all the time.

I initiate process with hg.exe file and then execute hg commands by passing arguments in to it.

1. process.init("hg.exe");
2. args["update"];
3. process.run(true,args,args.lenght);

But I am confused how I am going to use hstart.exe on top of it

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass hg commands as arguments in hstart.exe...that will do the trick !!!