# closing a command line window in Java

Tags: java

I have created a small Java application in which there is some code that executes a batch file. The execution of the batch file leads to the command line window to be opened and to display some output messages. I would like to know if there is some way in Java to call this command line window to be closed from within the program...Thanks!

Comment: Many answers seem to misunderstand the question. This is *not* about how to close the window after the command terminates, and *not* about avoiding a command window for the java process; it's about avoiding a command window for a bat launched *by the java process* (using `Runtime.exe` or similar, I presume).

Comment: maybe an example or more details would help to understand the real problem... Do you really need a batch file? Is it not possible to run the commands directly from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to NimChimpsky's answer:

If you run a batch file in Windows, Windows will automatically open a command window for the batch file, in case the batch file wants to print output or prompt for input. This also applies if you launch the bat file from a Java process.

Unfortunately, Windows itself apparently provides no way to launch a batch file without such a window. To avoid the window, you will have to run the batch file via some helper program. There are several available; google for "run bat no window" to find some.

If you just want the window to go away after the batch file terminates: That should happen automatically. If it does not, some program launched by the batch file is still running.

Answer (score 2):

the command window should close automatically when the batch file completes.

and to run a batch file in background/invisibly, check other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis)

Answer (score 2):

Start java by using `javaw` or `javaw.exe`.

`java` (`java.exe`) runs with an associated console window,
`javaw` (`javaw.exe`) is the same but without the console window.

see the documentation for the [java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) command.

On Windows also use `start` to invoke another *shell*

```
start javaw ClassName
```

I'm not sure for Linux&Co. Try using an & after the command to run it in the background

```
javaw ClassName &
```

---

The other way, closing the window from a batch started by Java:
I don't believe that is possible directly from within Java. You can only close the batch file by itself.
Is hard to help without knowing what that batch file is doing. You may try using the `start` command on windows or the & in Linux to run the process in the background (`start` has an option to open the window minimized [/MIN] or in the background [/B]). 
Or try some hack like using AutoHotKey or some system functionality (some WinAPI-DLL or equivalent in other systems).

Comment: That's not the question. The question is about a bat file launched *from the java process*, not about java.exe's command window.

Answer (score 0):

start /b [bat file name]

Comment: This is the way to run a bat file without opening a new window *from within an existing batch file* (i.e. while running inside `cmd.exe`). You cannot use this to directly launch a batch file from e.g. Java. You could use an intermediate batch file which just contains the "start" line, but *that* batch file would still quickly flash a window...

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but if the java program is running in cmd window, would it still do the same?