# Need Help running a batch invisibly from another batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, powershell-3.0

I have A batch file named x.bat, i need it to run y.bat invisibly
This is 
x.bat

```
     @ECHO off
     echo CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False>invisible.vbs
     wscript.exe invisible.vbs y.bat
```

y.bat

```
     @ECHO off
     dir>good.txt
     pause
```

When i run x.bat it is creating invisible.vbs but it is not opening y.bat invisibly
How to overcome this problem

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows XP or Vista: How can I run a batch file in the background (no windows displayed)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-di)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: **Modify your file.**

Save this one line of text as file `invisible.vbs`:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

To also be able to pass-on/relay a list of arguments use only two double quotes

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

Example: `Invisible.vbs "Kill.vbs ME.exe"`

Solution 2:

**Use a command line tool** to silently launch a process : `Quiet`, `hidecon` or `hideexec.`