# Taskkill with timeout in bat

Tags: batch-file, command-line, timeout, taskkill

I want something like this:-

```
taskkill 7z.exe after 50sec.
Execute few lines of codes without waiting for 7z.exe to be killed.
```

It will automatically be killed after 50sec, wherever the execution is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean ?  Waiting 50 seconds before killing 7z.exe

```
Timeout 50 
taskill /f /im 7z.exe
```

or you want to wait after killing then do some commands.

```
taskill /f /im 7z.exe
Timeout 50 
REM do commands here.
```

EDIT: New version for OP.

```
start "7z killer" cmd "/c Timeout 50 && taskkill.exe /f /im 7z.exe"
echo "do something immediately"
```

Comment: Wait 50 sec before killing 7z.exe. But do not pause the program. Keep executing other lines. Is the first one solution of that?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Please tell me a way to turn off the counting window.

Comment: probably could do it with the old invisible.vbs trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750808/need-help-running-a-batch-invisibly-from-another-batch  or http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a way to turn off the counting window, in addition to all the other stuff.

```
echo CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" ^& WScript.Arguments(0) ^& """", 0, False>Invisible.vbs
echo Timeout 50 ^&^& taskkill.exe /f /im 7z.exe>killer.bat
wscript Invisible.vbs killer.bat
echo "do something"
```

This creates two files in the same directory as itself, invisible.vbs and killer.bat then executes killer.bat invisibly with the 3rd line.

Comment: The `wscript` line replaces the `start` from the previous example.  That's how I make it invisible the counting window.

Comment: Ya , its invisible now. But the taskkiller is not running.i.e, I think the commands that were supposed to be executed in the new window(in your previous example) is not running now.