# Batch Duplicate Script

Tags: function, batch-file, command, duplicates, space

I made a batch script that duplicates the file I specify when opening the file via the command line. This is the script:

```
setlocal
set file=%1
for /f %%i in ("%file%") do (
set drv=%%~di
set path=%%~pi
set ext=%%~xi
set name=%%~ni
)
copy "%1" "%drv%%path%%name% - Duplicate%ext%"
pause
```

And this is the command I use:

```
D:\> "duplicate.bat" D:\testfile.txt
```

This example works perfectly, but when I have a space in the file name, for example:

```
D:\> "duplicate.bat" D:\test file.txt
```

The batch file reads the file name as `test` and the extension is left blank.

Hopefully this is possible :)

---

Ok, so thanks to [madhawa priyashantha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227526/madhawa-priyashantha) for helping with that problem, but now I realise that if I wan't to hide the cmd window that pops up when I run the script, I can use **[this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298564/3855392)**, but now the script fails to work on files with spaces again. Hopefully this is the last thing I need to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is tested and working .if you want to pass argument which consist spaces you need to wrap your argument otherwise bat consider next part after space as a next argument

```
@echo off
copy %1 "%~n1 - Duplicate%~x1"
pause
```

now you need to call this bat file like this

```
m.bat "D:\test file.txt"
```

and if no spaces,

```
 m.bat "D:\testfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.
D:> "duplicate.bat" "D:\test file.txt"