# Running a single silent script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting

I am looking to run a single script file to automate a KACE agent check in. My problem is I need the script to run silently so that the users are unaware it is being ran in the back ground. I have been told to use a vbs script to run the .bat silent, but why can't I run everything from the vbs script in the first place?? Here is my .bat script that currently does what I need it to aside from being silent.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\Program Files\Dell\Kace\" 
runkbot.exe 6 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Administrative account on your network or if you have a Domain and you are a Domain administrator you can use `PSExec` to invoke the script remotely.

Comment: I won't have the credentials when I need the script to run. The plan is to run the script on a vpn connection, so the connection software will be running the script.

Comment: Connection software can run .vbs scripts?

Comment: Ok, you can launch a executable or batch file from vbs calling Shell Com-Object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-di

Answer (score 0):

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\Program Files\Dell\Kace & runkbot.exe 6 0", 0, TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.vbs` file with a name like `silent.vbs` with the code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """" & sargs, 0, False
```

Then call it from a batch-file using `wscript.exe silent.vbs yourfile.bat <parameters for your batch-file>`

Or you could compile it as an exe file with a compiler like this one: http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=ob2e