# Hide CMD window after execute command line by the RUN

Tags: cmd, command, hide, black-box

How to hide CMD/BAT (the black box) WITHOUT using Vbscript, I dont like using VBSCRIPT because it slows down application before it autorun. So if you have a code to put into batch or CMD to hide the CMD/Bat file WITHOUT using VBScrpit. please let me know. 
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows XP or Vista: How can I run a batch file in the background (no windows displayed)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-di)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you:

## Solution #1

Use the `/min` slash after `START` command when starting your bat-file. This will start it with a minimized window. Example:
`START /min c:\mypath\mybatfile.bat`

## Solution #2

Create a shortcut to CMD.EXE. Open up Properties box of the shortcut.
In shortcut-tab change "run" to "minimized". 
In the target address (path and name of CMD) append path and name of your bat-file.

If you now doubleclick the shortcut, it should run CMD minimized, with no window showing, which in turn should start your bat-file.