# VBS gives error 'Expected end of Statement'

Tags: vbscript, syntax-error

Hi I'm trying to run this script but it's giving me 'Exepected end of statement.

```
wscript.exe "C:\test.vbs" "your_file.bat"
```

I'm putting the above in run.vbs, and I'm trying execute run.vbs from withing windows by double clicking the file. I get 'Expected end of statement' error

in the invis.vbs there is :

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Earlier I got this solution from : [Running Batch File in background when windows boots up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289498/running-batch-file-in-background-when-windows-boots-up)

Please advise.

Comment: The wscript.exe "c:\test.vbs" "your_file.bat" you can't put in run.vbs. It's batch script. Put that in a run.bat....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wscript.exe "c:\test.vbs" "your_file.bat" you can't put in run.vbs. It's batch script. Put that in a run.bat....

or

Modify run.vbs to look like:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run("wscript C:\test.vbs your_file.bat")
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
wscript.exe "C:\test.vbs" "your_file.bat"
```

is meant for textual input in the command prompt/console/dos box window. If you put it into a .VBS file, you (deserve and) get a syntax error. This:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

looks like valid VBScript code (whether in invis.vbs or test.vbs).

Trying to run a .VBS by double click is a bad idea if you plan to pass parameters to the script.

So you should start afresh and think about/describe clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to run your_file.bat silently in the background without and command prompt window open. That is whole idea behind it

Comment: @user726720 - and how should this process be started /invoked? By double click?

Comment: no I would put that in the registry in the RUN key for either Local machine or current user