# run batch after windows completely startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, startup, device-driver

My computer has a weird problem.
When I turn it on, after windows finished loads my network adapter does not work, so to make it work I have to remove the driver and install it again.

To do that, I'm running this as administrador

```
c:\devcon\devcon.exe remove = @"PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_10F0&SUBSYS_00008086&REV_05\3&33FD14CA&0&C8"
c:\devcon\devcon.exe rescan
```

And it is working pretty well, but now I want to run that automatically when windows startup.

I tryed to  schedule a task on windows, but it seems to be running before windows load the driver, so it is not working.

Is there a way to guarantee that it will run only after windows drivers are completely loaded and the error has already ocurred ?

Comment: Have a look at a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289498/running-batch-file-in-background-when-windows-boots-up?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It should be run automatically at the end of startup if you put it in the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line at the start that pauses it for a few minutes, before running devcon.

```
timeout 180 /nobreak
```