# How to make a .bat file autorun on pc startup

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I created this program to launch overwatch and chrome when i open it.

```
@echo off
start Overwatch.exe
start Chrome.exe www.youtube.com
timeout 2 > exit
```

Can I somehow make it run automatically after turning on my pc?

Comment: you really want to run overwatch every time? wont that get annoying

Comment: @L_Church I haven't actualy thought about that.

Comment: just saying you might want to run Team Fortress 2 instead. Way better ;). (Joking have fun with your games / whatever)

Comment: @L_Church ohh good old tf2 . I have a unusal hat in that game (yet only 400 hours). I need to get back to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Batch File in background when windows boots up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289498/running-batch-file-in-background-when-windows-boots-up)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the site you might want to look at:

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm

Basically you want

**Run a batch file at boot in Windows 8 and 10 users**

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Once the shortcut has been created, right-click the file and select Cut.
3. Press the Start button and type Run and press enter.
4. In the Run window, type shell:startup to open the Startup folder.
5. Once the Startup folder has been opened, click the Home tab at the top of the folder and select Paste to paste the shortcut into the folder.